# External libraries in Rollup

Tags: build, rollup

I am trying to build my application using Rollup rather than polymer-cli.
My `index.html` has the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/moment-precise-range-plugin/moment-precise-range.js"></script>
```

As well as other libraries which define a global variable.

I added these as "extraDependencies" in the good ol polymer.json file. What's the equivalent in Rollup? Or, how do you get Rollup to include those in the build?

At the moment, they are not included and the app obviously fails to run properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure `rollup-plugin-copy` is what I want.

```
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'


const copyConfig = {
  targets: [
    { src: 'node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js', dest: 'dist/node_modules/moment/min/' },
    { src: 'node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js', dest: 'dist/node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/' },
    { src: 'node_modules/moment-precise-range-plugin/moment-precise-range.js', dest: 'dist/node_modules/moment-precise-range-plugin/' },
  ]
}

const config = createDefaultConfig({ input: './index.html'})
export default { ...config, plugins: [...config.plugins, copy(copyConfig)] }
```

Bingo!
However, I do realise that a much better alternative would see me use these libraries importing them.

I will be happy to accept a different, better answer.

Comment: As it turns out, this is "the" answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers to your question, but I successfully replaced polymer-cli with rollup in polymer project using this https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/pull/370